# I'm trying to add the month values for each contact, but I get NaN

Tags: javascript, lwc

I have an object in which the office(office this is contact) contains months with values:

```
let data = {
    offices : [], 
    January : [],
    February : [],
    March : [],
    April : [],
    May : [],
    June : [],
    July : [],
    August : [],
    September : [],
    October : [],
    November : [],
    December : [],
    Total: []
};
```

[image]

i want to add all the values by month and then display in a table

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    let summ = 0;
    data.offices.push(result[i].office);

    data.January.push(result[i].months[0]);
    summ += data.January.amount;
    data.JanuaryTotal += result[i].months[0];
                
    data.Total.push(summ);
}
```

but for some reason I can't do it

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `data.January` is an array, not an object, so `data.January.amount` is going to be `undefined` - which is causing your `NaN`s when you treat it as a number. I can't tell you what you should do instead as the nature of the `result` data structure isn't clear to me or what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You just `push()`-ed into `data.January` in the previous line, so the object you've pushed is the one having an `amount` field. Thus `summ += result[i].months[0].amount;`. The next line remains complete garbage, as `data.JanuaryTotal` is not initialized to anything, and `result[i].months[0]` is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some thoughts to get you going.

You need to add your array elements.  Try to use reduce.

```
summ += data.January.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item)
```

Also, you need to initiaize `data.JanuaryTotal` to 0 at some point, you are adding to it, but never setting it.

Comment: No, that's not it. Note how the array grows in the loop.

Comment: @tevemadar 2 parts to my answer, both will end up with total.  actually, they seem to want both.

Comment: Ok, technically yes, or at least maybe. Just then you don't need the `+=`, only an `=`. Assuming they want a rolling sum in `Total`, but the entire thing still leaves a lot to the imagination.

Comment: @tevemadar, yep, i figured even if only 1 item in that array, it might fit the bill :)